# Select row name with max date with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

For example:

```
create table #t
(
    [ID] int,
    [Date] date,
    [Name] varchar(5)
)

insert into #t
values
(1, getdate(),'1-1'),
(2, dateadd(D,-10,getdate()),'2-1'),
(2, dateadd(D,-5,getdate()),'2-2'),
(1, dateadd(M,-1,getdate()),'1-2')

select * from #t
```

**I need to select [Name] for each [ID] with max [Data].**

Something like this:

```
select [1], [2]
  from ( select ID, [Date] from #t ) y
  pivot (
    max(y.[Date])
    for y.ID in ([1],[2])
  ) pvt;
```

Output:

```
     1            2
2017-04-28   2017-04-23
```

**but instead of [Date] i want to see [Name]**

what i want to view

```
 1          2
1-1        2-2
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: plus 1 for sample data,only one thing ,i would add is DBMS(like sqlserver/oracle..) and version

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
create table #t
(
    [ID] int,
    [Date] date,
    [Name] varchar(5)
)

insert into #t
values
(1, getdate(),'1-1'),
(2, dateadd(D,-10,getdate()),'2-1'),
(2, dateadd(D,-5,getdate()),'2-2'),
(1, dateadd(M,-1,getdate()),'1-2')

select [1], [2]
  from ( select ID, [Name] from #t ) y
  pivot (
    max(y.[Name])
    for y.ID in ([1],[2])
  ) pvt;
  drop table #t
```

Comment: Thank you, but this one is not correct. It returns max name, but i need return name with max date

Comment: If you tag the dbms it'd be much easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_nubmber() with date desc and pivot as below:

```
;with cte as (
select id, RowN = row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc), name from #t
) select * from 
(select id, name  from cte where rown = 1 ) s
pivot (max(name) for id in ([1],[2])) p
```

Comment: Thank you. You're right. 
But also I try to do it without using row_nubmber(), because, in non-example select i need to return not only withmax date, but also with max date in date range

Comment: What you mean by "max date in date range"? Can you provide examples? You can handle that while generating row_number

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
SELECT          [1], [2]
FROM            (SELECT         y.ID, 
                                t.Name
                 FROM           (SELECT     ID, 
                                            MAX([Date]) AS [Date]
                                 FROM       #t
                                 GROUP BY   ID ) y
                INNER JOIN      #t t ON y.[Date] = t.[Date]
                ) x
PIVOT
(
    MAX(x.Name)
    FOR     x.ID IN ([1],[2])
) pvt;
```

You can see this here -> http://rextester.com/ZGQGSC94965

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
                CREATE TABLE #t
                    (
                      [ID] INT ,
                      [Date] DATE ,
                      [Name] VARCHAR(5)
                    )

                INSERT  INTO #t
                VALUES  (1, getdate(),'1-1'),
                (2, dateadd(D,-10,getdate()),'2-1'),
                (2, dateadd(D,-5,getdate()),'2-2'),
                (1, dateadd(M,-1,getdate()),'1-2')

                SELECT  *
                FROM    #t;
                WITH    CTE
                          AS ( SELECT   ID ,
                                        MAX(Date) [Date]
                               FROM     #t
                               GROUP BY ID
                             ),
                        CTE2
                          AS ( SELECT   cte.ID ,
                                        cte.Date ,
                                        t.name
                               FROM     CTE
                                        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                                name
                                                      FROM      #t
                                                      WHERE     (ID = cte.ID AND Date = cte.Date) 
                                                    ) T
                             )
                    SELECT  MAX([1]) [1] ,
                            MAX([2]) [2]
                    FROM    ( SELECT    ID ,
                                        [Date] ,
                                        NAME
                              FROM      CTE2
                            ) y PIVOT ( MAX(y.NAME) FOR y.ID IN ( [1], [2] ) ) pvt
```

Result

```
        ID          Date       Name
        ----------- ---------- -----
        1           2017-05-02 1-1
        2           2017-04-22 2-1
        2           2017-04-27 2-2
        1           2017-04-02 1-2

        (4 row(s) affected)

        1     2
        ----- -----
        1-1   2-2


        (1 row(s) affected)
```